# Generate code from SPs using codesmith or MyGeneration?

Tags: vb.net, code-generation, codesmith, mygeneration

I have CodeSmith and MyGeneration tools. I have SPs in SQL server. I want generate VB.Net code for SPs (not for Tables). Which templates will support for this? Please share if you know any templates that generates VB.net code from SP?.

Answer (score 2):

[CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com) has VB.NET command (stored procedure) wrapper templates. They can be found in the Template Explorer under Database\CommandWrapper\VisualBasic. They were recently updated to also support SQL CLR Functions.

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski